# Can I instantiate a module multiple times?

Tags: c#, mvvm, unity-container, prism

I'm actually working on a project using Unity and PRISM and I would like to instantiate a module multiple times. I saw it is possible with MEF but I could not found out if it was possible with Unity.

Here is a simplified schema of how I want the app to be.

[image: Application's schema]

Please note that I don't want to instantiate multiple views of the same module, I want to instantiate the same module multiple times.

Is there any way to do this ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That's not the correct way of thinking about a module.  You should never be trying to instantiate a module multiple times.  You need to ask yourself what are you really trying to do.  It sounds like what you are wanting to do is run the code that is in the Initialize method of the module multiple times. which is not the same as loading a module multiple times.